# Shadows settings not showing on my light

Tags: light, shadows

So I'm watching Blender Guru on the donut stuff on Blender 2.8 and he clicks on his light but my settings aren't the same as his.

[image: My Blender] 
[image: Guru's Blender]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using *Cycles* Render Engine.
Switch to *Eevee* and all the options will be there.

*Render Tab > Render Engine > Eevee*

[image]

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the help